# Get list of dates from StartDate to EndDate

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can i get list of dates between start and end dates using linq or lambda expression.

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(13);
List<DateTime> ListofDates = //Contains list of all dates only between start and end date.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you want `Dates` and not `Datetimes` you better use `DateTime.Now.Date` instead of just `DateTime.Now`

I've edited SLaks code so you can get the list of dates you want.

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(13);
IEnumerable<double> daysToAdd = Enumerable.Range(0,
                                                (EndDate - StartDate).Days + 1)
                                            .ToList().ConvertAll(d => (double)d);
IEnumerable<DateTime> ListOfDates = daysToAdd.Select(StartDate.AddDays).ToList();
```

Note that I've added `+1` in the enumerable so you can have both the `start` and `end` date (you didn't specify it)

Answer (score 9):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, (EndDate - StartDate).Days).Select(i => StartDate.AddDays(i))
```

Comment: it will return me list of List<int> as we want list<datetime>

Comment: @SOFUser: This does return DateTimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DateTime> ListofDates = Enumerable.Range(0, (EndDate - StartDate).Days)
                                       .Select(i => StartDate.AddDays(i))
                                       .ToList();
```